# Advanced string handling in R - regular expressions, " ".format() & re.VERBOSE

Tags: regex, r, python-2.7

Python is an amazing language for handling strings. I've created some fairly advanced regular expressions that I'm thinking of porting to R. R has recently added the perl (?P) features but I'm not sure how to best do the following example in R:

```
import re

pill_unit = r"(?:PILL|CAPSULE)"
dosage = r"""
(?P<pills>
  ½|
  \d+(?:\.\d+|)|
  \bONE\b)\s*
{unit}""".format(unit = pill_unit)
compiled_regex = re.compile(dosage, re.VERBOSE)

print(compiled_regex.search("1 PILL A DAY").group("pills"))
```

sprintf() seems a clumsy compared to .format() where I can name my parameters and know that they end up in the right place.

Comment: I think `(?P<NAME>pattern)` is Python or PCRE based named capture buffer. Perl will parse it, but perl uses `(?<NAME>pattern) or (?'NAME'pattern)` syntax.

Comment: The regex has (?<name>pattern) if I've understood [the manual right](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/regex.html). I'm rather interested in the other features that Python offers, the .format() and the VERBOSE alternatives that actually make my huge regex readable...

Answer (score 0):

I have written a beta program that formats regex's into readable code. It does group analysis as well, balancing and a lot of other things. Misc special processing flags for engines. Its really unique to see very large expressions in a formatted fashion.

Example

On these, the group processing flag is turned on

```
(?P<pills>
  ½|
  \d+(?:\.\d+|)|
  \bONE\b)\s*
(?:PILL|CAPSULE)
```

into

```
1    (?P<pills>
          ½
       |  
          \d+
          (?: \.\d+ | )
       |  
          \bONE\b
1    )
     \s*
     (?: PILL | CAPSULE )
```

then, into

```
(?P<pills>½|\d+(?:\.\d+|)|\bONE\b)\s*(?:PILL|CAPSULE)
```

then this

```
1    (?P<pills>
          ½
       |  \d+
          (?: \.\d+ | )
       |  \bONE\b
1    )
     \s*
     (?: PILL | CAPSULE )
```

Comment: Nice, does it handle comments as well? Is the program in R or a separate package? I would think that writing your own .format() function should be pretty straightforward but it surprises me that there is none by default.

Comment: Hi Max. Sure it handles comments, using selectable overlays of naturally occuring linebreak or heruristics. It parses regular expressions and and applies heuristics in formatting. Its no trivial feat. In the ideal state, its a stand alone graphical interface program with multiple checkboxed options. There is about 15 optional states right now centerred on a core state that focuses on grouping (all grouping constructs). Compression, thresholds, engines, all to tailor to the visual construction - which is very subjective. I may offer free $5-$10 donation software soon.

Comment: I would like to license binaries when its fleshed out. Its just huge in its capability right now, getting it consolidated is another thing. I haven't run it through its first refactoring yet. Thanks for asking.